# VisualCode vs Git - добавить файлы проекта

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, phpstorm, pipelines

перешел с PhpStorm на VSCode и возник вопрос - как правильно добавлять файлы проекта в локальный репозитарий если VSCode не выгружает эти файлы как это делал PhpStorm.
К примеру проекты это web сайты.
Мне нужно самостоятельно все выгрузить с сервера, и потом уже работать с ними локально отправляя пуши в ветку из которой по pipeline они будут уходить на dev\prod ?
Или как правильно организовывать эту работу?

Comment: "не выгружает эти файлы" - это какая операция в терминах гита? Выгружать с сервера - через pull. Открываете слева Source control, жмете на три точки (которые more actions), там жмете pull.

Comment: При чем тут термины Git? Ситуация такая - никакого репозитария еще нет, ни локального ни удаленного. В PhpStorm при создании remote проекта, файлы с сервера выгружаются на локальную машину в директорию, в ней я уже могу выполнить git init и далее связать ее с удаленными репо. Но в VSCode ничего не грузится на локальную машину при создании проекта (по сути директория с поддиректорией .vscode и файлом sftp.json с настройками соединения и все...)

Comment: при этом в локальной папке появляются копии remote файлов которые я редактировал на прямую на сервере. И если я в их директории сделаю git init, то потом у меня каждый раз при редактировании новых фалов они будут появлятmся и нужно будет делать git add .

Comment: "В PhpStorm при создании remote проекта, файлы с сервера выгружаются на локальную машину в директорию" - откуда они на сервере берутся? Это git сервер или ftp или расшаренная папка, или что это?

Comment: >>>откуда они на сервере берутся? Это git сервер или ftp или расшаренная папка, или что это? - Это или sftp или ftp доступ к серверу с сайтом. Моя цель настроить CI/CD в итоге, ну или для начала хотя бы просто две ветки main и dev (из main могу пока просто руками по WinSCP или консоли по scp копировать на сервера - сначала на тестовый из ветки dev а потом на боевой из ветки main). Вопрос именно в том как мне создать изначально локальную репу, с файлами проекта, мне их просто надо выгрузить по FTP в директорию, затем настроить .gitignore и далее git init с привязкой к удаленной репо или как?

Comment: Устанавливаете ftp или sftp расширение в vscode, через него получаете файлы, и дальше работаете.

Comment: да, но в таком случае каждый новый открытый файл с удаленного сервера на редактирование, будет добавлен в директорую в которой проинициализирован GIT, и мне нужно будет каждый раз при коммитах эти файлы добавлять по git add . Вот я и спрашиваю, может их правильно было бы предварительно все выгрузить с сервера (как это делал PhpStorm) в эту директорию и один раз добавить все (нужные только) командой git add. ?